# Pass params into custom url route

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I created custom url route like this:

```
Router::connect('/subjects.details', array(
    'plugin' => 'subjects',
    'controller' => 'subjects',
    'action' => 'details'
));
```

However that action/view needs a parameter.

So when I go to link like `localhost/foo/subjects.details/12` it gives me missing controller error.

> Missing Controller
>
> Error: Subjects.detailsController could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class Subjects.detailsController below in file:
>   app/Controller/Subjects.detailsController.php

How do I add id param for this url?

Comment: You can also use `subject-details` instead of `subject.details`, and use CamelCased controller name in route `'controller' => 'Subjects'`.

Comment: @user3082321 that doesnt change anything

Comment: It must have changed error message. What's the error message.

Comment: @user3082321 it hasn't changed anything at all. Anyway, solution has been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the param in the url and in your action as well:

```
  Router::connect('/subjects.details/:id', array(
        'plugin' => 'subjects',
        'controller' => 'subjects',
        'action' => 'details'
    ));
```

Comment: `http://localhost/tmc/subjects/subjects/details/1`  returns a page with data while `http://localhost/tmc/subjects.details/1` returns error page: ` Error: The requested address '/tmc/subjects.details/1' was not found on this server.`

Comment: it seems like cakephp interpretes subjects.details as Plugin/Controller

Answer (score 0):

Lasers answer returned another error. It basically added new key `'id' => '1'` into `$this->params` array instead into `$this->params` 's `'passed'` key array. By changing it into this it works:

```
Router::connect('/subjects.details/*', array(
  'plugin' => 'subjects',
  'controller' => 'subjects',
  'action' => 'details'
));
```

Comment: That is a variable length parameter route which matches /subjects.details/12/12/1/24/4/45/45/5/ ...... It's not the one you need if you intend to retrieve a single document

Comment: Then what else would you suggest since `:id` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. You have to passed the params and then it'll start working. Here is the way-

```
  Router::connect('/subjects.details/:id', [
    'plugin' => 'subjects',
    'controller' => 'subjects',
    'action' => 'details'
   ],
   [
    'pass' => ['id']
   ]
  );
```

And your method should look like this-

```
public function details($id){
  //....
}
```

I hope this can be helpful. Thanks.